# How to automatically execute a function when a component is loaded in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I created a page to handle a "Cart", where Cart details are retrieved from a database. When the "Click me" button is clicked, all the retrieved data is shown in a react component.

I want data to be shown without clicking a button, which I would like to achieve through a function that executes automatically when the component gets loaded. How can I achieve it?

Here is my code

```html
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {selectPost} from '../../actions/productAction';

class cartDetails extends Component{


    createListItems(){
        //let cart = {product: [],total: 0}
        return this.props.allPost.map((item)=>{
            console.log(item);
            return(<div> 
               
                <p key={item.id}>{item.product} <br/> {item.description} <br /> {item.price} </p>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }


    totalPrice(){
        let cart = {product: [],total: 0}
        return this.props.allPost.map((item)=>{

            cart.product.push(item.price);
            console.log(cart.product);
           
              let total =  cart.product.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0);
              
            return(<div> 
                <h3>Total is {total}</h3>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }


    render(){
        if(!this.props.allPost){
            return(<h2>Click the button first.</h2>);
        }
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.createListItems()}
                {this.totalPrice()}
                
                
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateProps(state){
    return{
        allPost: state.allPosts
    }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({selectPost: selectPost}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateProps,matchDispatchToProps) (cartDetails);
```

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {fetchPost} from  '../../actions/productAction';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class CartComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>this.props.fetchPost()}> Click Me </button>
        </div>
        )
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchPost: fetchPost}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, matchDispatchToProps) (CartComponent);
```

Comment: componentDidMount will help you there.

Comment: @BabarKhan Where can I use it? I don't have any state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger a method automatically when the component loaded, you might want to use one of the lifecycle methods `componentDidMount`. You might want to keep or remove the button depending on your requirement.

```js
class CartComponent extends Component{
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPost();
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>this.props.fetchPost()}> Click Me </button>
        </div>
        )
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({fetchPost: fetchPost}, dispatch);
}
```